# adding new lists to a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a 2d array

```
ArrayList<List<Customer>> list;
```

Each customerNode stores two customers. I want to add a new list of customers to the `list` array if neither of the customers exist in any of the current `List<Customer>` in `list`. However, when I run this it doesnt add the 'newR' to the list.

```
for(customerNode s: customers){
    count++;
    if(!LinearSearch2(s.getOne(), s.getTwo())){
        System.out.println("Test");
        ArrayList<Customer> newR = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        newR.add(s.getOne());
        newR.add(s.getTwo());
        list.add(newR);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
List<Customer> newR = null;
newR.add(s.getOne());
```

You need to initialize `newR` by assigning it a new instance of `List`, such as `new ArrayList<Customer>();`.

Otherwise, your `newR` reference is pointing to `null` and you can't invoke methods on it without the JVM throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I just realised that as soon as I posted, the problem is that it still doesn't add the 'newR' to my list, although I am not given any errors

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: the problem was with a loop elsewhere in my code